# Erratic if statement. "Returns" value on true clause, then before exiting, it returns value on false clause

Tags: java, android, generics, if-statement

### [UPDATE] Issue is fixed with "erratic" if statement. Answer is in the comments. I created a new question to deal with my other issue - [Multiple Buttons, 1 ClickListener using generics, Strategy Patter - All buttons only do the same operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615590/multiple-buttons-1-clicklistener-using-generics-strategy-patter-all-buttons)

I have encountered a strange if-conditional logic flow that should not be happening.

Basically the method `listenOn(...)` in the class `Click` should not keep on creating new instances of the listener. One is good enough, so I guard against those unnecessary creations.

However, when I setup a simple test in `MainActivity` just before all the `setOnClickListener`'s to check out the `listenOn(...)` method, I seen that the first call to that method works as intended, and the second time appears to work...

...except that **after** the `return` occurs in the true-clause, it skips down directly to the `return` of the false-clause; skipping the creation of the new Listener, though.

**I cannot understand why it is doing that**. There is an error in my code, because no matter what button I press, it only does the division operation. I added Generics, and this issue may be from that.

By the way, I am trying different ways to create Listeners. I am not looking for "the best way", or "the standard way", I am looking to learn different things, so don't attack the method I used to create Listeners.

---

I would like it if you could explain...

**The behavior of the if-statment**

and

**Why only division is happening when I click any button**

---

### Click.java

```
public class Click<T extends Operation> {

    private T operation;

    private View.OnClickListener listener;

    public Click(T operation) {

        this.operation = operation;

    }

    public View.OnClickListener listenerOn(final MainActivity UI) {

        // ******************************************************
        // First pass - goes to false-clause, and returns that new listener
        // Second pass - goes to true-clause, returns the old listener, and then goes to the 
        //               false-clause and returns the listener; however, it skips the creation of 
        //               the new View.OnClickListener. Why??
        // ******************************************************
        if (listener != null) {

            return listener;

        } else {

            listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    double total, num1, num2;

                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(UI.txtNumber1.getText().toString());
                    num2 = Double.parseDouble(UI.txtNumber2.getText().toString());

                    total = operation.execute(num1, num2);

                    UI.txtResult.setText(Double.toString(total) + " -v5");

                }
            };

            return listener;

        }
    }

}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddition);
    Button btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubtract);
    Button btnMul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMultiple);
    Button btnDiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDivide);

    txtNumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
    txtNumber2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
    txtResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    // Testing - Checks the if-conditional of listenerOn()
    // ******************************************************
    Click click = new Click<>(Add.OPERATION);
    View.OnClickListener listener = click.listenerOn(this);

    listener = click.listenerOn(this);
    // ******************************************************


    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new Click<>(Add.OPERATION).listenerOn(this));
    btnSub.setOnClickListener(new Click<>(Subtract.OPERATION).listenerOn(this));
    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(new Click<>(Divide.OPERATION).listenerOn(this));
    btnMul.setOnClickListener(new Click<>(Multiply.OPERATION).listenerOn(this));

}
```

Comment: If you're running the code in a debugger, it's normal to see the instruction pointer jump at the end of method frame when exiting from a method. The conditional works anyway. For the question about operations: please post some of your `OPERATION` code.

Comment: I would suggest to use logs to see easily if it goes into the true or false clause.

Comment: Yes, I was using the debugger, but I thought I remember seeing them jump to the end-bracket, not the return statement. Anyway, I will update my code soon. I might change the question to be related to the Operations soon, too. Maybe within the next hour

Comment: @laalto I created a new question for my other issue here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615590/multiple-buttons-1-clicklistener-using-generics-strategy-patter-all-buttons