# Multiple Buttons, 1 ClickListener using generics, Strategy Pattern - All buttons only do the same operation

Tags: java, android, generics, listener, strategy-pattern

I have been looking at different ways of making Listeners in Android. I encapsulated the listener in a separate class called `Click`. I have also used the **strategy pattern** to encapsulate logic and that is interfaced with the enum type `BinaryOperator`. What I have is a simple calculator that you probably seen online already - 2 input numbers, 1 result, and 4 buttons (+, -, *, and /).

There is an error in my code, because no matter what button I press, it only does the division operation. I added Generics, and this issue may be from that.

By the way, I am trying different ways to create Listeners. I am not looking for "the best way", or "the standard way", I am looking to learn different things, so don't attack the method I used to create Listeners.

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddition);
    Button btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubtract);
    Button btnMul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMultiple);
    Button btnDiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDivide);

    txtNumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
    txtNumber2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
    txtResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new Click<>(Add.OPERATION).listenerOn(this));
    btnSub.setOnClickListener(new Click<>(Subtract.OPERATION).listenerOn(this));
    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(new Click<>(Divide.OPERATION).listenerOn(this));
    btnMul.setOnClickListener(new Click<>(Multiply.OPERATION).listenerOn(this));

}
```

### Click.java

```
public class Click<T extends Operation> {

    private T operation;

    private View.OnClickListener listener;

    public Click(T operation) {

        this.operation = operation;

    }

    public View.OnClickListener listenerOn(final MainActivity UI) {

        if (listener != null) return listener;

        listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                double total, num1, num2;

                num1 = Double.parseDouble(UI.txtNumber1.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(UI.txtNumber2.getText().toString());

                total = operation.execute(num1, num2);

                UI.txtResult.setText(Double.toString(total) + " -v5");

            }
        };

        return listener;

    }

}
```

### BinaryOperation.java

Where `Add.OPERATION`, `Subtract.OPERATION`, etc... come from

```
public enum BinaryOperation {

    Add (new Operation(new Add())),
    Subtract (new Operation(new Subtract())),
    Multiply (new Operation(new Multiple())),
    Divide (new Operation(new Divide()));

    public final Operation OPERATION;

    private BinaryOperation(Operation operation) {

        OPERATION = operation;

    }

}
```

### Operation.java

```
public class  Operation {

    private static IOperationStrategy strategy;

    public Operation(IOperationStrategy strategy) { this.strategy = strategy; }

    public double execute(double a, double b) { return strategy.executeOperation(a, b); }

}
```

### IOperationStrategy.java

```
public interface IOperationStrategy {

    public double executeOperation(double a, double b);

}
```

### Add.java (One of the 4)

```
public class Add implements IOperationStrategy {

    @Override
    public double executeOperation(double a, double b) {

        return a + b;

    }
}
```

Comment: As for the code itself-  even trying the weird stuff you're doing its implemented horribly wrong.  You wouldn't both take an object in your Click constructor and use generics- you'd use one or the other.  And here generics add no value, as you aren't using the generic type anywhere-  you just need to take an object of the base type.  If you don't understand inheritance and generics, don't even begin to attempt code like this-  you'll screw up your learning curve rather than help it along.  Patterns shouldn't be something you mess with until you have a few years of DESIGN experience.

Comment: There is absolutely no need (or use) for generics in this case. You can replace `T operation` by `Operation operation`.

Comment: here is your issue: `private static IOperationStrategy strategy;` the same strategy is used for all operations, in this case the last one called, `new Divide()`

Comment: Thanks @njzk2 that worked, it was because of `static`. I will have to analyze my previous iterations to see what that issue did not show up before and learn about Java and other programming related things; expanding my learning curves into other directions.

Comment: I will look into modifying the use of Generics. I have gone through several iterations, and one of them took me in this direction, but it was flawed. I restarted from scratch thinking it could still work - not realizing I didn't need the generics